# Using Prisma Client with Supabase Edge Functions

Tags: javascript, npm, prisma, deno, supabase

I am trying to use the generated `@prisma/client` together with Supabase Edge functions. When running `npx prisma generate` the default location would be in my `node_modules` folder, which is a problem since I can't access it when using edge functions. I therefore added the `output` property to my `prisma.schema` file and the client gets generated in the correct location. My `schema.prisma` looks like this:

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  output          = "./../supabase/functions/_shared/prisma-client"
}

datasource db {
  provider  = "postgresql"
  url       = "..."
  directUrl = "..."
}

model Users {}
```

I tried importing the client in multiple ways into my edge functions:

```js
// Attempt #1 (according to: https://deno.land/manual@v1.14.2/npm_nodejs/std_node#loading-commonjs-modules):
import { createRequire } from 'https://deno.land/std@0.155.0/node/module.ts'
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url)
const cjsModule = require('../_shared/prisma-client')
/* Error: worker thread panicked TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'timeOrigin')
    at https://deno.land/std@0.155.0/node/perf_hooks.ts */
/* Note: I also tried different versions of the std library */

// Attempt #2:
import { PrismaClient } from '../_shared/prisma-client'
/* Error: Unable to load a local module: "file:///C:/Users/.../supabase/functions/_shared/prisma-client".
  Please check the file path. */

// Attempt #3:
import { serve } from 'server'
import { PrismaClient } from '../_shared/prisma-client/index.d.ts'

serve((_req: Request) => {
    const prisma = new PrismaClient()
})
/* Error: worker thread panicked Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration
    at file:///home/deno/functions/_shared/prisma-client/index.d.ts:53:11 */
```

I furthermore tried to convert the module from CommonJS into an ESM module using the [`cjs-to-es6`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cjs-to-es6) npm package. But this also didn't work.

So my question is: Why my attempts failed, and (perhaps more importantly) how do I get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from https://deno.land/manual@v1.28.3/node/how_to_with_npm/prisma

```js
import { Prisma, PrismaClient } from "../generated/client/deno/edge.ts";
import { config } from "https://deno.land/std@0.163.0/dotenv/mod.ts";

const envVars = await config();

const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  datasources: {
    db: {
      url: envVars.DATABASE_URL,
    },
  },
});
```

Note that for Prisma to work in Edge Functions you will need to proxy through something like Prisma Data Platform: https://deno.land/manual@v1.28.3/node/how_to_with_npm/prisma#setup-prisma-data-platform

So you might want to consider using `supabase-js` instead as it works in Edge Functions out of the box: https://github.com/supabase/supabase/blob/master/examples/edge-functions/supabase/functions/restful-tasks/index.ts

Comment: I came to the conclusion that supabase-js would be the better choice in this case. However, it lacks typescript support for my database models, which was the reason to use prisma in the first place.

Comment: You can generate types for supabase-js from your Database using the CLI: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/api/rest/generating-types

Comment: I was just about to say I need to thank whomever took the time to self-answer this and lo and behold we've worked together. Thanks Thor!